# Photoshop can not save pdf file while using Unicode languages in text layers

Tags: windows-7, adobe-photoshop

I have created a Photoshop project with some layers. I have some text layers that their languages is Unicode like Arabic and Persian. While I'm using such text layers, Photoshop can not save the project as PDF file.

I know I can save the whole project as an image, but I want to keep texts separated, so I can make searches in my PDF file...

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably file this bug with Adobe so they can work on it (Hopefully) also, why don't you save the text as a text file, and create the images separately, then assemble the PDF in something like Adobe Acrobat?

Answer (score 1):

You could convert text to raster and save as image. You will get a bigger file and the PDF will not be searchable etc but it is a work around.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But My goal is to save a searchable PDF file...

Comment: Please update your question to reflect your needs  :)